# How to prevent Mysql database from being changed/updated/deleted?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am preparing a MySQL test where user will see a small database and we will display some questions. User will answer the questions as queries. He will create a query and run it and see if he get's the desired result.

All questions are based on 'select' queries questions. So before running the query I want to confirm that there's nothing in the query that changes the current status of the database. User can't obviously run update, delete , insert etc any other types of queries that modify the database.

How can I do this? Is there some library that can help me? I am currently simply searching for the keywords insert, update and delete in the query string to prevent this. I am using PHP and codeigniter MVC.

Comment: create database user which didnt have (delete,update,etc) role attached on it. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/how-to-create-separate-users-in-phpmyadmin-each-one-cant-see-others-databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the user with only `SELECT` privilege assigned to it like:

```
"GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'username'@'host_or_wildcard' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Now the user with `username` have only `select` privilege.

Answer (score 1):

While you can restrict the actions based on the settings granted to the user, which will prevent unauthorized actions as the safest solution, you can use preg_match to check for the existence of certain restricted words in the query.  However, there may be use cases where some of these words may be used in a SELECT query IF you need them for a text based lookup =, LIKE, REGEX, etc.

To handle this you could strip off anything inside quotes or apostrophes from the string so they are ignored.

```
$query = preg_replace('/"[^"]+"/','', $query);
$query = preg_replace("/'[^']+'/",'', $query);
```

Then, with the string you have left, check for a list of prohibited MySQL words or phrases.

```
if(preg_match('/[alter|set|update|insert|delete|replace|into|grant]/',strtolower($query))) {
    $bad_query = true;
}
```

Granted this is a more complex actual PHP solution.  The safest bet is to restrict access of your MySQL call, however if your goal is to test for specific syntax - you can accomplish that.

For information about the GRANT options and the set of commands each allow, you can use this URL as a great resource:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html